# How to run Eclipse Oxygen on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-lion, osx-mavericks

I've been running Eclipse Mars on Mac OS X 10.7.5 successfully for a few years. However as I'd like to upgrade to Java 10 soon I tried to update to Eclipse Photon last week. The installer however crashed immediately. I've been googling it for a while but couldn't find anything so I created [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538204) bug report. There I was told that Eclipse Photon won't run on anything lower than OS X 10.11. However, I would be able to run Eclipse Oxygen successfully when replacing the launcher with the Neon.3 launcher. Point is, how do I replace that launcher?

Also, I was wondering if I can run Eclipse Photon on OS X 10.9.5. I may be upgrading to that version by the end of this year (I have my reasons to not upgrade to 10.11 in the near future).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following to links in that bug report says the Eclipse Photon will definitely **not** run on 10.9 since all native libraries have been built based on 10.10 [516805](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516805)

Comment: Well, at least I should be able to run Oxygen then. Any advice for replacing the launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution myself. Unfortunately, it is not possible to run Eclipse Photon on Mac OS X 10.7.5. Officially, Eclipse Oxygen is not supported either and it will crash when trying to open it. It is however possible to run Eclipse Oxygen on Mac OS X 10.7.5 by replacing the launcher with the Neon launcher.

1. You will need to download both the Eclipse [Oxygen](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R/eclipse-inst-mac64.tar.gz) and [Neon](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R/eclipse-inst-mac64.tar.gz) installer.
2. Run the Neon installer and install Eclipse Neon.
3. Right click the Oxygen installer -> Show contents and do the same for the Neon installer. Then replace Contents/MacOS/eclipse-inst from Oxygen with the Contents/MacOS/eclipse-inst file from the Neon installer.
4. You can now successfully open the Oxygen installer and install Eclipse Oxygen.
5. After installing it, open the contents of Eclipse.app for both Oxygen and Neon. Then replace Contents/MacOS/eclipse in Oxygen with Contents/MacOS/eclipse from Neon.
6. You can now remove Eclipse Neon and successfully open Eclipse Oxygen.